# Writing a query to get all records in a group based on an item in the group

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Sorry for the unhelpful title, but hopefully I can explain this well enough.

Lets say I have three tables,

```
Item
  ItemKey
  ItemName

Group
  GroupKey

GroupItem
  GroupKey
  ItemKey
```

Given an ItemKey, how would I get all records from the item table that belong to a group containing the item key?

So if I have

```
Item
   1    ItemA
   2    ItemB
   3    ItemC

Group
   1
   2
   3

GroupItem
   1     1
   1     2
   2     1
   2     2
   3     2
   3     3
```

Passing in 1 will return ItemA and ItemB, but not ItemC since there is no group with both ItemA and ItemC in it.

Comment: And if you passed in 2, you'd get ItemA, ItemB & ItemC because they are all in groups with ItemB? Am I understanding correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select distinct ItemName
from Item I
inner join GroupItem GI
    on I.ItemKey = GI.ItemKey
where GI.GroupKey in
    (select GroupKey
    from GroupItem
    where ItemKey = @Param)
-- @Param is the input parameter. Change for you
-- DBMS
```

or:

```
select distinct ItemName
from GroupItem GI_MemberOf
inner join GroupItem GI_Map
    ON GI_Map.GroupKey = GI_MemberOf.GroupKey
inner join Item I
    on I.ItemKey = GI_Map.ItemKey
where GI_MemberOf.ItemKey = @Param
-- @Param is the input parameter. Change for you
-- DBMS
```

Comment: Works great, thanks. Is there a performance benefit for choosing one over the other though?

Comment: 1) When comparing performance of alternate queries look at the execution plan on your real data. 
2) In the past, joins generally happened faster than subqueries, but query optimizers have gotten good enough, often the same execution plan will be chosen. Then it comes down to readability.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a sub-query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.ItemName
FROM GroupItem gi JOIN
  Item i ON gi.ItemKey = i.ItemKey
WHERE gi.GroupKey IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT GroupKey FROM GroupItem WHERE ItemKey = @Param
)
```